# Phase error MASM assembly from user input string

Tags: file, assembly, input, masm, file-writing

I'm trying to use a user inputted string to create a file. I'm using 0Ah function to get the user input. I think the error occurs once I use 3Ch to create the file. The code I'm using to create the file is:

```
            mov ah, 3Ch                     ; create file
            mov cx, 0
            mov dx, offset filename + 2     ; where the characters start
                                              since user input string 
                                              starts 3 bytes over
            int 21h
            mov handle, ax                  ; save file handle
```

Then I have a loop that basically writes a string to the file using 40h

```
WRITE:
            mov ah, 40h                 ; write
            mov bx, handle          
            mov cx, lstring             ; length of string
            mov dx, offset string       
            int 21h
            loop WRITE                  ; I know it's a infinite loop, just an example
```

The error is "Phase error between passes" points to the "WRITE:" line, but it seems that if I remove the WRITE label it will put the error on the next label. From what I can google, there's something wrong with the variables in that the second pass as it sees them as a different size? How do I fix this error?

Here's my code before I hit the first label

```
            .code
main:   
            mov ax, @data               
            mov ds, ax

            mov     ax, 4000h               ; set up display string
            mov     bx, 1                   ; to monitor
            mov     cx, lstring1            ; length of string1
            mov     dx, OFFSET string1      
            int     21h

            mov ah, 0Ah                     ; set up service to capture buffered input
            mov dx, offset filename         ; where to find the input
            int 21h

            mov ah, 3Ch                     ; dos service to create file
            mov cx, 0
            mov dx, offset filename + 2     ; I still to need add NULL to the end of filename
            int 21h

            mov handle, ax              ; save file handle
```

On further messing around, it seems if I deleted the code that outputs to monitor with the 4000h, the error disappears.

Comment: _"How do I fix this error?"_ We can't possibly know that since you haven't said what the _exact_ error message is. Also, don't assume that file i/o functions will succeed; do error checking after each such interrupt.

Comment: Seconding @Michael 's message.  Edit your original message, and cut and paste the phase error message. From that, we'll be able to suggest the source code line(s) that you should also include to help resolve the error.  By the way, nice commenting.  Your code is legible; a rarity on the internet these days.

Comment: By the way, I think you have source and destination backwards in this line, `mov ax, handle  ; save file handle`

Comment: Also, post complete code. Since you say you think there is something wrong with the variable size, it would help if you showed us how the variables are declared... Presumably you didn't declare something as word, but you use them as words here, or maybe you declared `string` wrong so you can't take its offset. Could also be a problem with `WRITE` being defined more than once, or similar.

Comment: "loop write" means CX--, IF CX > 0 JUMP... You are using CX to tell interrupt the string length, later, you do "loop write", you are using CX again with an uncertain value. Two solutions : don't use CX to loop (so you can't use "loop" either), or, push CX before the file write and pop it right after. Show the whole code to take a better look.

Comment: @Michael I edited my original post to clarify some things.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez It seems to be my display code that messes things up. I edited my original post to clarify.

Comment: @Jester All my variables are declared with db and the handle is declared with dw.

Comment: The filename entered by user is a string that ends with chr(13), the interrupt requires the filename ends with chr(0), you have to change it before opening the file.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571779/how-to-copy-from-one-file-to-another/29571980#29571980

Comment: You need to post a minimal complete and verifiable example that we can use to reproduce the problem. You should also mention what version of MASM you're using, and what command line arguments you used to invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you get the user input via DOS function 0Ah. This function delivers you a CR-terminated string. But the subsequent DOS function 3Ch to create a file expects a ZERO-terminated string. There's no knowing what could have been created!

You don't actually save the handle. Better use

```
mov handle, ax  ; save file handle
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried adding 0 but the "phase error between passes still exist". I guess I copied save file handle wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Phase error comes up when a label is assumed in data segment and not present in code segment.  To fix it you can assume ds:code-seg OR by mov ax,cs:label.  Qualify the label that gives phase error